# Regular Expression for not matching any of the exact words

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that matches everything except for three exact words. For instance , I don't want it to match red, green and blue. So it should not match red, green or blue but it should match evergreen and greens.

Is there any way to do this in regular expression?

Comment: Present what you have so far, what your approach is and the flavor you chose to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update

To capture `greens` or `blueberry` we can add a `\b` to the look-ahead (so it has to be the singular word "blue", "red", or "green"):

```
(\b(?!red\b|green\b|blue\b)\w+\b)
```

which [results in](http://regexr.com?354ld):

<kbd>something</kbd>
green
<kbd>evergreens</kbd>
red
<kbd>fred</kbd>
blue
<kbd>navyblue</kbd>
<kbd>greens</kbd>
<kbd>something</kbd>
<kbd>blueberry</kbd>
<kbd>else</kbd>

---

Depending on your flavor of regex, you can use a negative look-ahead:

```
(\b(?!red|green|blue)\w+\b)
```

Which basically means:

```
(                         # begin capture
  \b                      # word delimeter
  (?!red|green|blue)      # exceptions
  \w+                     # capture any word-characters (equiv: [a-zA-Z_])
  \b                      # word delimeter
)                         # end capture
```

Example: http://regexr.com?354la

<kbd>something</kbd>
green
<kbd>evergreens</kbd>
red
<kbd>fred</kbd>
blue
<kbd>navyblue</kbd>
<kbd>something</kbd>
<kbd>else</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, Brad! That is similar to what I was going for but the problem is that it would not match greens. That is the hurdle I am unable to solve. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @ZShah: Okay, give that a shot

Comment: That works beautifully! Thanks so much!! It solves the problem and learnt lot of new things as well, especially combining word boundaries in look-ahead.